# How to break up expression into distinct sub-expressions?

Tags: swift, string, singleton, static-data

I got this error in Swift
"The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

Here is the code that is throwing the error.

```
             let obj = self.AddressList[indexPath.row] as! Address
//            let a:String! = obj.street+" ,"+obj.city+" "+obj.country
//            let b:String! = obj.country
            StaticData.singleton.cardAddress = obj.street+" ,"+obj.city+" "+obj.country
            StaticData.singleton.AddressID = obj.id
            StaticData.singleton.cart_addresstotal = obj.total_amount
            StaticData.singleton.cart_addressFee = obj.delivery_fee
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dismiss(animated:true, completion:nil)
            }
```

in particular it is this portion of the code in which the error is pointing towards:

```
    StaticData.singleton.cardAddress = obj.street+" ,"+obj.city+" "+obj.country
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the `+` operator with String concatenation. In general, using String concatenation is the preferred approach over using the `+` operator.

```
StaticData.singleton.cardAddress = "\(obj.street) ,\(obj.city) \(obj.country)"
```

Comment: you are a life saver thank you so much! worked great! ...not sure why I didn't just think of that 

Comment: @Aaron34 Glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it. If you're unsure how to do that, you can read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).